# Can i get access over file in FileWriter Filter of Directshow

Tags: directshow

I have read the FileWriter Filter :

" The File Writer filter can be used to write files to disc regardless of format. The filter simply writes to disc whatever it receives on its input pin, so it must be connected upstream to a multiplexer that can format the file correctly. You can create a new output file with the File Writer or specify an existing file; if the file already exists, it will be completely overwritten with the new data. "

So my question is :

I am using the FileWriter filter for writing my audio stream into the disc. Before writing the file in the disc i want to access that file , so can it be possible or should i make my own custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

File writer filter does not not provide you with options to change file sharing mode while the file is being written to. Additionally, in most cases your accessing the file before it is finalized makes no sense: the files are rarely written incrementally, file finalization changes data in the middle of the file and your accessing data before the file is closed might get you bad/incomplete stream.

Answer (score 0):

Roman R is right. Writers are for writing. If you need transform data - write your own Transform filter.

You can ask me directly [here](http://shadowofaero.blogspot.com/search/label/DirectShow).